# Sum discrepancy in R

Tags: r, precision

Consider the following:

```
probs <- c(0.05, rep(0.95/99, 99))
```

which clearly sums to 1 according to

```
sum(probs).
```

However, when I type

```
sum(probs == 1)
```

I get 0 (i.e, boolean FALSE).

Why does this discrepancy occur? Shouldn't the two commands be equal?

As a test, I compared these with all.equal():

```
all.equal(sum(probs), sum(probs == 1))
[1] "Mean relative difference: 1"

all.equal(sum(probs == 1), sum(probs))
[1] "Mean absolute difference: 1",
```

which seems to suggest inequality, but why?

My guess would be numerical precision handling in R (i.e., Machine epsilon) is not stringent enough.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're comparing 0 and 1 in your `all.equal` comparisons. `sum(probs)` is `1`, while `sum(probs==1)` is `0`. `all.equal(sum(probs),1)` on the other hand is `TRUE`

Comment: you mean to do `sum(probs) == 1` ? Read this out. [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: @thelatemail The reason ask is because I am performing a simulation where 100 objects are selected from according to the distribution of probs. Would there then be a easy way to ameliorate the 'discrepancy' (I am not able to run the simulation otherwise), perhaps by increasing the Machine epsilon in R?

Comment: @JarrettPhillips - my point is you're not even comparing the right things. Why would you expect 0 and 1 to be equal given any standard `.Machine$double.eps` ? `sum(probs)` is indeed `1`. `sum(probs==1)` is `0` because `probs==1` returns 100 values of `FALSE`. Summing 100 `FALSE` / `0` values is still `0`. Notice the slight difference in the placement of the `()` in the code suggested by Ronak.

Comment: @thelatemail I just noticed the change Ronak made to their earlier comment. Anyway, I see the point now - thanks.